# Cannot access the private network when connecting through a VPN to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, ssh, vpn, wireguard

I can't access the router nor the Raspberry Pi through SSH when connected to it through a VPN, which is hosted in the Raspberry Pi.

The issue doesn't appear in my phone, so the issue is in Windows. I also get an error in Brave:

> Your Internet access is blocked. Firewall or antivirus software may have blocked the connection.

I am not sure what to do, I am unfamiliar with this kind of issue in Windows. I am using Windows 11 as OS and Raspberry Pi OS and pivpn as OS for the Raspberry Pi and VPN provider.

Both networks have as a gateway 192.168.0.1. The IP of the VPN network is static. The IP of the network in which Windows is connected is dynamic. The Raspberry Pi has a static IP address.

I am pretty sure the issue is in Windows firewall or something like that, but I am not sure where.

I also noticed that my networks shows as private but when I activate the VPN I see two networks, the ethernet network and the VPN network. This last one is connected as a public network. but I don't think that is the issue because at first both showed up as public.

I also tried connecting both my phone and PC to the VPN so I can use Sunshine but the phone doesn't detect the PC.

Comment: It must comes from routes added with your VPN conflicting with your the main network... Could you provides details about precise routing ? It may permit to help you troubleshooting this issue

Comment: Not sure if it helps but when everything is connected to the same router as the one in which the vpn is i still get same error. Also. How i provide you with this data? Any command that i should run or specific information? Sorry. I am kinda newby with this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is really weird: I restarted my PC and the issue solved itself.

Sorry I can't give a reason of why this happened, if you ran into the same problem as me feel free to comment, maybe we can talk about it.